# Create listview with button using Xamarin and SQL Server

Tags: c#, xamarin, sql-server-2012, asp.net-web-api2

I have created a project in which I am retrieving data from the database and display it into a `ListView`. See image below.

[image: listview]

Here is the code for retrieving data for the `ListView`

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
  public static  Context context;
    public static List<UserInfo> UserInfoList = new List<UserInfo>();

    public static ListView ListView;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main); 
        ListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.Listview);

        GetList list = new GetList();
        list.Execute();
    }
    public class GetList : AsyncTask
    { 
        Context con;
        protected override Java.Lang.Object DoInBackground(params Java.Lang.Object[] @params)
        {
            System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient( );

            var _WebApiUrl =  string.Format("URL");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage messge = client.GetAsync(_WebApiUrl).Result;
            var Return_EventList = messge.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var EventList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserInfo>>(Return_EventList);

            foreach (var data in EventList)
            {
                UserInfoList.Add(data);
            }
            return true;
        }
        protected override void OnPreExecute()
        {
            base.OnPreExecute();

        }
        protected override void OnPostExecute(Java.Lang.Object result)
        {
            base.OnPostExecute(result);
            ListView.Adapter = new UserInfoListAdapter(context, UserInfoList);
        }

    }


    class UserInfoListAdapter : BaseAdapter<UserInfo>
    {
        private List<UserInfo> mItem = new List<UserInfo>();
        private Context context;
        public UserInfoListAdapter(Context mcontext, List<UserInfo> mItems)
        {
            mItem.Clear();
            mItem = mItems;
            context = mcontext;
            this.NotifyDataSetChanged();

        }
        public override UserInfo this[int position]
        {
            get
            {
                return mItem[position];
            }
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return mItem.Count;
            }
        }

        public Context MContext { get; private set; }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        { 
            View listitem = convertView; 
            listitem = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.ListViewDesign, parent, false);
            TextView TxtName = listitem.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TxtName);
            TextView TxtNumber = listitem.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TxtNumber);
            TxtName.Text = mItem[position].firstname;
            TxtNumber.Text = mItem[position].contact_no;
            listitem.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                Toast.MakeText(parent.Context, "Clicked " + mItem[position].firstname, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            };

            return listitem;
        }
    }

}
```

I want to put buttons in the `ListView`, one per row. Here is the example of how I want to implement it

[image: listview example]

Now when user click on button, a pdf file should download based on current id from database. For example in my database `xray` id is `1`, so when user download pdf for `xray` it should download based on id which is `1`

Answer (score 0):

- Place TableLayout in your 'ListViewDesign' android layout in order to
  get required view (or it can be achieved by Linear Layout by setting
  its orientation horizontal and its layout_weight)
- Place Button in Fourth Column
- Remove Click Event from GetView Method
- Access Button in GetView Method

  ```
  Button DownloadButton = view.FindViewbyId<Button>(Resource.Id.btn_download);
  DownloadButton.Click += delegate { DownloadFile( link + mItem[position].Id ) };
  ```
- Add Namespaces

  ```
  using System.Net;
  using System.IO;
  using System.Text;
  ```
- Add a new method in your listView Adapter Class

  ```
  private void DownloadFile(string url)
  {
     var webClient = new WebClient();
     webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) => {
     var text = e.Result; // get the downloaded text
     string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
     string localFilename = "downloaded.txt";
     string localPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename);
     File.WriteAllText(localPath, text); // writes to local storage
  };
  var url = new Uri("http://xamarin.com");
  webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
  webClient.DownloadStringAsync(url);
  RunOnUiThread(() => {
      Toast.MakeText(this, "Download Completed", ToastLength.Short).Show();
  });
  }
  ```

Comment: suppose if i have pdf file in my database will this code download pdf from database based on id?

Comment: No, You can use this code to download file from a link based on their Ids

Comment: i will save path for pdf in database will it download from path?

Comment: Yes, It will by passing link to DownloadFile Method

Comment: `{ DownloadFile( **link** + mItem[position].Id ) };` where this link from